# basic python 3 module issue

Tags: python, module

Okay, so I'm trying to write a module for class to load up a basic prime number checker. We have samples to look from, and I'm going to copy what I have so far... But I'm pretty lost on how to write this, and then for the program to actually call the module (should be import xxxx.py right?)

Don't be too harsh, I'm not the only one in my class struggling with this. Youtube and my search results on here haven't really helped. Thanks in advance for yet, another basic question.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3


#Program Name
print("Prime Number Checker")


def factor_count(num):
    factor_count = 0
    print("The factors are: ")

def main():    
    choice = "y"
    while choice.lower() == "y":
        #user input
        num = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
        if num <= 1:
            print("please choose a value greater than 1. ")
            print()
        else:
            for i in range(1, num+1):
                if num%i == 0:
                    print(i)
            if factor_count == 2:
                print(num, "is prime")
            else:
                print(num, "is not prime!")

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    main()            


print()            
print("goodbye")
```

Comment: You're running before you can walk.  This is a whole mess of stuff that can't work.  Make something very small that works first.

Comment: I thought it was a mess... Back to the drawing board I suppose.

Comment: okay, so i fixed it some, but it's not where it needs to be. It still keeps saying non-prime numbers are prime (actually all numbers.) Also, I'm unsure where I need to put the break in to stop the loop.

Comment: You should probably research the [algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) first.

Comment: Keith, probably the least helpful thing you could have said man. I've been grinding in my book for hours... and re-wrote this thing 22x already. Have better advice??

Answer (score 0):

Couple of points, here is how I would write the program :

1. Don't use the same name for variables and function names `factor_count`. So when you write `if factor_count == 2` it is always false.
2. You aren't updating the value of variable `choice` after every run
3. the way of finding primes is also very inefficient.

---

```
def main():
    choice = "y"
    while choice.lower() == "y":
        factor_count = 0
        # user input
        num = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
        if num <= 1:
            print("please choose a value greater than 1. ")
            print()
        else:
            for i in range(2, num):
                if num % i == 0:
                    print(i)
                    factor_count += 1
            if factor_count == 0:
                print(num, "is prime")
            else:
                print(num, "is not prime!")
        choice = input('Do you want to continue?(y/n) : ')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Prime Number Checker")
    main()
    print()
    print("goodbye")
```